# Run all exe file from one folder one by one

Tags: batch-file

Im learning batch file coding. How can I execute a bunch of exe files from one folder. One by one, I got a recycled code below. if youll execute it, if does nothing. please help me recode it.

```
    for /r %%m in (*.exe) do (start /wait (%%m)

)
pause
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. The do belongs to the end of the previous line. Executing a series of exe and only once trying to evaluate an errorlevel would get you only the last result. You'll have to put everything following the do into a (code block) and as a result have to deal will delayed expansion.

Comment: Please read the help for the `FOR` command by typing this at the cmd prompt: `FOR /?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /r %%f in (*.exe) do (start /wait %%f /quiet /norestart)
```

Added some code such as /quiet to execute it in quiet mode and /norestart to avoid the unit from automatically rebooting.

Answer (score 3):

```
for %f in (*.exe) do start /wait %f
```

Comment: Have edited my code above, thanks for your help, but it says "The system cannot find the file (E:\folderName\filename.exe". But I'm pretty sure that the file name exist in that drive and folder.

Comment: have you changed to that directory first?

Comment: What do you mean? The batch file and .exe files were in the same folder.

Comment: well that work for me. remember to replace % with %% in a batch file

Comment: Okay, some of the files were successfully executed, but some file returned the error. Do this relates to the windows compatibility mode? I mean 64bit from 32 bit? 
I got a 64bit OS, but it only runs the x86bit .exe files. Sorry, I'm not familiar to these architecture.

Comment: it will execute all exe files in the directory 1 by one, no matter what architecture, if you only wanna run 32 bit code you must name the files accordingly to specify its 32 bit then use a different forloop approach

Comment: Now I see, I renamed all the files and removed the spaces" " from the files who have returned error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: to fix that just wrap %F in quotes like start /wait "%F"

Comment: Yeah, I firstly did that. But the same error is prompting. So my last resort is to remove the spaces " ".
I don't know if there is a glitch or something like that.